# My loop does not work inside my getJson call

Tags: jquery

my console.log(url) return the same thing every time but when i console it outside the json call, everything work just fine. why is that and how i can fix it? the for loop is counting before the Json make the call. for example when i console the i inside the Json it returns the number 8, 8 times but if i console the i outside de json but inside the for loop it returns 0 to 7

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","noobs2ninjas"]; 
    for(var i = 0;i<channels.length;i++){ 
        var url='https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+channels[i]+'?client_id=pd57d4ktf8rjarn9q3qgtv4owbr5q0'; 
        console.log(url);
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){
            console.log(url);    
        });
 }});
```

Comment: Can you please make it clear? It is working as expected. What are you expecting?

Comment: I suspect this could be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111

Comment: the for loop is counting before the Json make the call. for example when i console the i inside the Json it returns the number 8, 8 times but if i console the i outside de json but inside the for loop it returns 0 to 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two links in the comments give reasons for why this is happening but the specific reason you are seeing this is because your `getJSON` call is asynchronous. Your loop will complete before the callback that you pass to `getJSON` is executed. That is why your `console.log` outside of the callback is what you expect but the one inside the callback logs out the same end state 8 times.

The following snippet hopefully will give you a clearer indication of what is happening. Notice how the "In loop" lines all happen before any of the "In callback" lines.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("In loop", i);
  
  // Simulate an asynchronous request
  setTimeout(function() {
    /*
      By the time this executes, i has been incremented
      to 5 so the loop is finished.
    */
    console.log("In callback", i);
  }, 1);
}
```